# Configuring MySQL to allow generation of Primary Key values

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, primary-key

This may be a relatively simple question to answer. But, I'll include all of my code just for completeness.

I'm generating alpha-numeric primary keys for my MySQL tables using the class found [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type). However, when I upload a row to the database, I get this error:

```
FlushError: Instance <User at 0x1d47110> has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a load() event.
```

So, here is the code when I use to GUID code from SQLAlchemy source:

**User.py**

```
from app import db
from app.custom_db.GUID import GUID

class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(GUID(), primary_key = True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique = True)
  email_stub = db.Column(db.String(30), unique = True)

  def __init__(self, name, email_stub):
    self.name = name
    self.email_stub = email_stub

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

When I just use `db.Integer`, it works fine. But, like I said I want to user alpha-numeric `uuid4()` primary keys. How can I make my MySQL database not complain when I do so?

Comment: Just want to add that using UUID as primary key is not a good idea. InnoDB uses the primary key in each secondary key, and that adds 16 bytes for each key. You best use an integer as primary key (and use AUTO_INCREMENT) and make the GUID a secondary key. Also, even more important, store the GUID as BINARY(16). It might not be important with 1000 users, but with a million it will be.

Comment: Really? Is an auto-incremented integer safe? I feel like that would make it easy to pose as other users if you could guess their primary key.

Comment: You should never expose your primary key when it is not random. You expose the random GUID (as hex) and use the primary key internally. You'll save lots of network traffic and space going from ~16-32 bytes to 4 or 8 bytes (INT/BIGINT).

Comment: There actually are very many reasons *to* use a UUID as primary key, exposed or not. Just as there are reasons to use auto-incrementing ints and reasons NOT to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to assign a [default generation function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html) to the primary key.  Here we'll also use a simplified version of the [backend-agnostic GUID type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html?highlight=guid#backend-agnostic-guid-type) example so that we see real uuids:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import uuid

Base = declarative_base()

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String(32)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return "%.32x" % value
        else:
            return MNone

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(value)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(GUID(), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String(40), unique=True)

e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(e)  # just for testing here
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

s.add_all([User(name='u1'), User(name='u2'), User(name='u3')])
s.commit()

for guid in s.query(User.id):
    print(guid)
```

Comment: And this will check to make sure the uuid is unique right? What happens if it's not. Will it throw an error or just try again with another uuid?

Comment: it won't throw an error because when you get your first non-unique uuid, the earth will have fallen into the sun and the computer won't be running anyway.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates